# SQL how to get only desired selects inside a SP

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server DB with a few catalogs.

Then I create a new SP that will get all the system catalogs:

```
-- company
SELECT [companyuid]
      ,[masterentity]
      ,[description]
      ,[externalid]
      ,[isactive]
  FROM [dbo].[setup_company]
WHERE [masterentity] = @masterentity
AND  isactive = 1

-- park
SELECT [parkuid]
      ,[companyuid]
      ,[description]
      ,[externalid]
      ,[isactive]
  FROM [dbo].[setup_park]
WHERE isactive = 1

-- store
SELECT [storeuid]
      ,[parkuid]
      ,[description]
      ,[isactive]
  FROM [dbo].[setup_store]
WHERE isactive = 1

-- family products
SELECT [familyuid]
      ,[description]
      ,[isactive]
  FROM [dbo].[setup_product_family]
WHERE isactive = 1
```

Now, I need this SP to be flexible, so that I can return only `company` catalog or `company` and `users`.

I was thinking of creating a new table named `catalogs`, and there I set all the catalogs that I have and then attach some rule to the SP.

Comment: Seems complicated -- why not just pass 4 booleans which specify which to return -- of if you are really lazy one string that contains the names of the ones you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing this,

```
enum Flg
{
 Company=1,
 Park=2,
 Store=4,
 Family=8
}
```

you can take only one variable in sp but pass the value in variable like this,
Suppose only Company then @Flg=1,company and park both then @flg=3,company and family only then @Flg=9.

**Understanding the concept here is more important**

Then in your proc you can write like
for Testing you can pass any damn value in @Flg.

```
Declare @Flg int=6

SELECT [companyuid]
      ,[masterentity]
      ,[description]
      ,[externalid]
      ,[isactive]
  FROM [dbo].[setup_company]
WHERE [masterentity] = @masterentity
AND  isactive = 1 and (@Flg & 1=1)
--union all
-- park
SELECT [parkuid]
      ,[companyuid]
      ,[description]
      ,[externalid]
      ,[isactive]
  FROM [dbo].[setup_park]
WHERE isactive = 1 and (@Flg & 2=2)
--union all
-- store
SELECT [storeuid]
      ,[parkuid]
      ,[description]
      ,[isactive]
  FROM [dbo].[setup_store]
WHERE isactive = 1 and (@Flg & 4=4)
--union all
-- family products
SELECT [familyuid]
      ,[description]
      ,[isactive]
  FROM [dbo].[setup_product_family]
WHERE isactive = 1 and (@Flg & 8=8)
```

You can also store multiple checkbox value here where type cannot be more than 10.

Answer (score 2):

Add additional params(as may condition u need)

Check for the condition using if block if the block should be executed or not.

Below is sample

```
    create proc
    @masterentity int ,
    @iscompany smallint  =0,
    @ispark  smallint  =0
    as 
    -- company
    if (@iscompany <>0)
    begin 
    SELECT [companyuid]
          ,[masterentity]
          ,[description]
          ,[externalid]
          ,[isactive]
      FROM [dbo].[setup_company]
    WHERE [masterentity] = @masterentity
    AND  isactive = 1
    end
    -- park
    if (@ispark <>0)
    begin 
    SELECT [parkuid]
          ,[companyuid]
          ,[description]
          ,[externalid]
          ,[isactive]
      FROM [dbo].[setup_park]
    WHERE isactive = 1
    end
```

Comment: what about sending in one parameter like "1,2,3,4,5" where 1 = company, 2 = park, etc.?